# Payflow Pro Not Working

Tags: paypal, magento-1.5, paypal-sandbox, magento

I seem to have everything setup correctly, however my transactions are not being placed and I get an error saying “There was an error processing your order, please contact us or try again later",  when I hit the “PLACE ORDER” button.

I had double checked that the merchant email. partner id, user, vendor and the password are provided correctly and the test mode is enabled. 
My payflow pro account is not activated, so its a test account. Is that the reason for my problem ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Enable Debug on the module and check the output of the log in var/log/ and check the response, and make sure your using Test Mode?

Comment: yes i had already enabled the debug mode and i am using the test mode. here is my output in the var/log file
[result] => Array
        (
            [result] => 12
            [pnref] => V35A1F13CEF5
            [respmsg] => Declined
            [hostcode] => D
            [prefpsmsg] => Review: More than one rule was triggered for Review
            [fps_prexmldata[844]] => <triggeredRules><rule num
            [request_id] => 16d136fdb74d8649717eb00e5a4202c6
            [result_code] => 12
        )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a normal process then, I would contact PayPal as they are declining the payment, due to a rule on their side, over max limit, etc.

Other option would be is that you could change the request sent to increase the verbosity of the error but it would only shed further light and would help in troubleshooting.

The request string needs to appended with Verbosity=Medium to increase the output.  I believe this can be done via class `Mage_Paypal_Model_Payflowpro:_buildBasicRequest()` and modify the `setVerbosity()`

Refer to [PayPal Documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_PayflowPro_Guide.pdf) for information.

Comment: is this because I am using HTTP instead of HTTPS ?

Comment: I wouldn't think so.  I think that would be a different error, this appears to be more in the authorization of the actual card.

Comment: Ok. I have posted a ticket in the paypal tech support. Let me check what will be there feedback. Thanks Vern, have a great day :-)